# Insert json data into mysql table file JSON data contain more keys than I have in my mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have JSON array. In which some json key contains mysql table column or some are not in my table.

I'm creating query in PHP like this :

```
$fields_query = $fields_query . strtoupper("$key") . " ,";
$values_query = $values_query . "'" . $value . "'" . " ,";
```

How can remove json data which are not in my table?

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the steps given below

1. Get the column names of your tables in an array say `$column_names` as described in the link https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/get-column-names-from-table-in-mysql-php/
2. Now, get `json_decode()` the JSON data in another array `$data`. Remember to extract associative array.
3. Declare another array `$saveArray = [];`.
4. Remove columns you do not want to be part of insert query from the array `$column_names`. You may use `array_search()` and `unset()` functions for this purpose.
5. Iterate first over array `$data`.
6. Have another for loop inside the loop from last step. This for loop will iterate over the array `$column_names`.
7. Now simply use the available column name in the innermost loop to extract its value from the data row from $data available in parent for loop.
8. You just need to prepare a final insertion query for each data row.
9. Run the Query!

Please let me know if these steps helped you.

Comment: So quick... :) Welcome ... :)

Comment: When I post question I though I can do something like this and it exact what you suggest and it worked. Thanks Again.